# display list with new line in a cell

Tags: templates, jxls

I use JXLS with templates to generate excels files.
I worked pretty good.

However, I would like to know if there is a way to display a list of String in a cell, with new line after each element, instead of display a new cell for each element.

Example : i have a list of employee

${employees.name} would give me :

---

- employee 01
- employee 02
- employee 03

---

instead of :

---

- employee 01

---

- employee 02

---

- employee 03

---

Answer (score 0):

You should create a StringBuilder with **"\n"** (break line) in your string:

**//In your Object**

```
public String getAsString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new  StringBuilder();
    sb.append("line1").append("\n").append("line2").append("\n");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**//In your Sheet**

```
${object.asString}
```